# Hibernate looking for a non-existent column

Tags: hibernate

I'm in no way a hibernate pro, but I do understand some of what is going on. Here's my issue. For some reason last week our build introduced an error where hibernate is looking for a column we had eliminated from the database and code over a month ago. I have absolutely no idea why its looking for this and the stack traces are more useless than tits on a bull. Has anyone seen an issue like this before? If so how did you fix it?

Comment: Could your build be using an old dependency?

Comment: Likely, but I can't seem to track down where its at. How would I fix that?

Comment: Are you using hibernate annotations or mapping files?  What is failing?  Unit testing in the project itself?  Functionality in a project that has said project as a dependency?

Comment: We use annotations. As far as what is failing, its our functional tests. I have been looking at this for about 2 days and no idea why its even looking for the column in the first place since I can't even find an annotation for it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue after changing the field and getter/setter name. I also can't find any instance of the "non-existent" column name in the code.

Comment: Wish I had a solution for you. Unfortunately this problem magically resolved itself after about a week of frustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, Hibernate is looking for a default column name, even if you haven't explicitly put the column name in your annotations.

Maybe you can turn these options on in your hibernate.properties file  :

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create 
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

... and look for your faulty column in the generated DDL. Then you 'll have a hint on which Entity/Entity Relationship is causing you troubles.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by default column name, but I wasn't able to find the hibernate.properties file. Even if I could, I'm not sure it would help. I know what column its looking for...I just can't figure out why it's looking for it, or how to make it stop. The column no longer exists in the code anywhere, nor do the annotations for it. Which leaves me incredibly confused.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you use an old copy of the jar.
If your functional test runs against server than delete the temp folder of the server.
Try to run a unit test on fresh copy of this jar. Try a simple unit test only for this class.
Decompile the jar to see if you use refresh copy.

Comment: Well to be honest we deploy from war files to test against, and these are updated daily. I did try this however and no dice.